# Extracting attributes as a string/labels as a string into a separate column

Tags: r

I have imported a `.dta` file (Stata) into R. The dataset has two variables which have the following structure:

```
$ S003     :Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:341271] 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Country/region"
  .. ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%8.0g"
  .. ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:199] NA NA NA NA NA 4 8 12 16 20 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:199] "Missing; Unknown" "Not asked in survey" "Not applicable" "No answer" ...
 $ S003A    :Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:341271] 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 392 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Country/regions [with split ups]"
  .. ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%8.0g"
  .. ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:199] NA NA NA NA NA 4 8 12 16 20 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:199] "Missing; Unknown" "Not asked in survey" "Not applicable" "No answer" ...
```

In R, the entries in the columns are displayed as numbers (i.e. 8) which refer to a country name.

I would like to extract that country name as a string to and add it as a column to my dataframe. Something like:

```
df <- extract(df, countryname, into = c("countryname"), "([a-zA-Z]+)")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post data using `dput()` function, also add wanted output

Comment: Sorry, bit of a noob still.. Could you elaborate?